# How to hide html element by specific class combination?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have other company's html, show three lines:

```html
    <div class="classA classB classC">A_display</div>
    <div class="classB classC">B_no_display</div>
    <div class="classC">C_no_display</div>
```

I need A_display display, and let B_no_display\C_no_display hide.

The classA, classB, classC's name is known and the class combination will not change.

Can I use CSS selector make it? Like using this css:

```css
.classA .classB .classC{
  /* todo how to display A_display, don't display B_no_display C_no_display*/
  /* display: inline !important;*/
}
.classB .classC {
  display: none;
}
.classC {
  display: none;
}
```

Then the page show only one line:

```
    A_display
```

Comment: a space between selectors will look for descendants. if you want to select elements having those classes you should omit the whitespace `.classA.classB.classC` [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CSS selectors can be used to hide specific elements based on their class combinations. The updated CSS code to achieve the desired result is as follows:

```css
.classA.classB.classC {
  display: block;
}

.classB.classC {
  display: none;
}

.classC {
  display: none;
}
```

This will make the **`A display`** element visible while hiding the **`B no display`** and **`C no display`** elements. CSS selectors check each element for the exact class combination, and the **`display`** property is used to show or hide the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the whitespace between class names like `.classA.classB.classC`

```css
.classA.classB.classC {
  display: inline !important;
}

.classB.classC {
  display: none;
}

.classC {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA classB classC">A_display</div>
<div class="classB classC">B_no_display</div>
<div class="classC">C_no_display</div>
```